# Android: My app won't run if I put Switch OnClickListener on a FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, android-fragmentactivity

I'm a beginner at Android programming. Please help me with this issue.

#### Activity_main.xml

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="70dp"
     android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
     android:background="#2c3e50"
     android:enabled="false"
     android:minHeight="15dip"
     android:padding="3dp"
     android:text="Read More..."
     android:textColor="#fff"
     android:textColorHint="#fff"
     android:textSize="9sp" />
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
Button switchButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
switchButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Caraga_Agusan_del_norte.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

This code won't run.

Comment: where is your onCreate(..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to run

```
Button switchButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
switchButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Caraga_Agusan_del_norte.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

after you have called `setContentView`, and the button has to be declared inside the `xml` you provide as parameter to `setContentView`

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    Button switchButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    switchButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Caraga_Agusan_del_norte.class);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
  });
}
```